# atmega16 single port checking in while() loop or if()

Tags: c, microcontroller, atmega, avr-gcc

The Atmega16 `PORTC` is used for push button, and renamed as so

```
#define LEFT_S       PINC&(1<<2)
#define RIGHT_S      PINC&(1<<3)
#define UP_S         PINC&(1<<4)
#define DOWN_S       PINC&(1<<5)
#define OK_S         PINC&(1<<6)
```

And am trying to put it in loops like

```
while (OK_S);
```

or

```
if (UP_S);
```

What is the consideration?

`while (OK_S)` or `if (UP_S)` is not working in functions.

But by taking the key value to a variable via a function, then I can check it.
When I use a function `ch = Key_pressed();` `while(ch==1)` is working perfectly.

```
int Key_pressed(void)
{   
   while(1) {
      if (LEFT_S)  { while (LEFT_S);  return 1; }             
      if (RIGHT_S) { while (RIGHT_S); return 2; }
      if (UP_S)    { while (UP_S);    return 3; }
      if (DOWN_S)  { while (DOWN_S);  return 4; }
      if (OK_S)    { while (OK_S);    return 5; }
   }
}
```

The mentioned error is show when simulating in Proteus

Comment: It seems to me that you should get a couple of [good beginners books to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It is very much unclear what you are asking. What is "not working"? What's the behavior? Can you give an example?

Comment: `while(..)` is loop you spin there and `if(..)` is validation statement. You can decide what you need to perform on your needs of the application.

Comment: A [mcve] would be really helpful to make this question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the mistaken of Precedence of the != operator is higher than of the & (bitwise and) operator
i was used as 
while `(OK_S != 1)`
it means as

```
while (PINC & ((1 << 6) != 1))
```

to the C compiler  would prefer something like

```
while ((PINC & (1 << 6)) != 1)
```

But the correct way is

```
while ((PINC & (1 << 6)) != (1 << 6))
```

so i corrected the  macro definition as

```
#define OK_S (PINC & (1 << 6))
```

And working correctly .

Comment: `while ((PINC & (1 << 6)) != (1 << 6))` is not good. If you change OK_S to a different port, the testing against `(1 << 6)` will fail. Test it **always** against 0 or false, implicitly or explicitly. Parenthesis in macro definitions are a must. Always.

Comment: I dont want to change the port right now ,please mention How to test  against 0 or false .in this case

Comment: `if (S_OK)` or `if (!S_OK)` or `if (S_OK==false)` or `if (S_OK==0)`. The last three are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you `Key_pressed();` does the debouncing internally and you do not have to worry about it.

If you check the pin status you may receive tens or hundreds fake "key presses" as the metal contacts bounce for the very short time:
[image]